# How do I alter table to add defaults?

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure, sql-server-2008-r2

I'd like to modify a table that already has data in the database to have a column reflect default data when it is populated.

Specifically, I'd like to take two columns:

```
[Created] [datetime] NULL ,
[CreatedBy] [varchar](50) NULL ,
```

And change them to have defaults like the following:

```
[Created] [datetime] NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
[CreatedBy] [varchar](50) NULL DEFAULT USER_ID(),
```

Can something like this be accomplished with an alter table statement? I'm using Azure so I can't edit the tables in the GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.TableName
  ADD CONSTRAINT df_Created DEFAULT (GETDATE()) FOR Created;

ALTER TABLE dbo.TableName
  ADD CONSTRAINT df_CreatedBy DEFAULT (USER_ID()) FOR CreatedBy;
```

Check [the documentation for ALTER TABLE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx)...